# How to update the node key in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, key

[image]

How to rename the `14-04-2017` node?

Comment: Do you want to update "14-04-2017" to something else?

Comment: Can you please edit your original post to clarify your question? Thanks

Comment: yes guys, "14-04-2017" is ID of child node, and I want to update to somthing else, how can do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to rename a node. You'll have to get the values of the node, save it to your DB using the new name and delete the old node.

Comment: I was think that too, but it is a bad idea bro :(

Comment: Bad idea? Could you expound?

Comment: If you are saving and lose internet or somthing broken before you delete it -> database still save old child node bro, I tested this!

Comment: I understand. No need to *shout* though. If the data you need to write (or in this case, *replace*) is *critical*, you should use a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Transaction.Handler). This scenario is tackled in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).