# Firebase Realtime Database Edit Key and keep children

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to edit the name of the classroom shown in the image below without losing the children data, how to do that in android ?

[image: my database structure]

Comment: Is that the only key you want to edit? Or will you need to edit more keys in the future?

Comment: There is no API call to rename a key. You'll have to create a new node with the data and delete the old one. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107274/is-it-possible-to-rename-a-key-in-the-firebase-realtime-database, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46449627/how-can-i-rename-a-branch-node-in-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43510725/how-to-update-the-node-key-in-firebase, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456443/how-to-move-firebase-child-from-one-node-to-another-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for doing this. There is no API that allows you to change the name of a node in a Firebase database. What can you do instead, is to create another node with the desired name, containing the same childrens and then remove the old one.

Comment: what is the syntax ?

Comment: The flow as follows: attach a listener on `11B Boys` node, get the `DataSnapshot` object and then write it in the same location with another name. Also don't forget the remove the old one. That's it!